# z-index pseude element over parent, but under the rest

Tags: css, z-index

z-index pseude element over parent, but under the rest
So if I have two divs the first one(orange) should be over the second(green).
Then I add a pseude element that should be over the first one (orange) but under the second one (green.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnorg/1Lypbs3u/

```css
.box {
    width: 28px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #ff6d00;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 6;
}

.box:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: #2d2d2c;  
    z-index: 4;
}

.box-under {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div> <!--orange-->

<div class="box-under"></div> <!--green-->
```

How is this possible?

So the black goes over orange and behind green (Dont mind sizes etc)
[image: So the black goes over orange and behind green (Dont mind sizes etc)]

Comment: It's the same as you use any element inside `.box` - it can't be under its parent.

Comment: So should the order of layers from bottom to top be: green, black and orange? And, can this markup change slightly?

Comment: The order should be mixed
Black over orange, orange over green and green over black.

Comment: @Gnorg Erm.. that confused things. I think without a screenshot we can't help. The order you've suggested doesn't sound possible all at the same time.

Comment: I've edited my post and added a picture.

Comment: You will need at least 3 divs, if image describes your requirement well...p.s. ''green over black'' - whole black div is not visible, on image, so this  is not mandatory, right?

Comment: I don't understad your question. Can you please elaborate? Correct that the whole black isn't visible.

Comment: Ok, from what we can see: black div is not 'under' green, or green is not over black... We assume that one part of black div is hidden behind green, FROM your description, but since it is NOT clearly visible ON IMAGE, we can see this image as: one small black rectangle over bigger orange rectangle, orange over green. This makes things little easier, i guess.. :)